# How can the user's progress be linked?

Tags: bubble.io

I am building a prototype of an educational game/course in bubble.io. I would like to link the user's progress to a progress bar so that when he/she logs back in he/she starts in the corresponding section.

I tried to put a direct variable in the user but I don't need it to store what the user does but what he did. I was going to create a separate variable but it was not properly bound to the user.